# Code Analysis Using VS2012 - Missing Dll References / GAC

Tags: visual-studio-2012, code-analysis, gac, gacutil

I'm trying to run code analysis on my project and I'm plagued by lots of DLL resolve issues.

I've already Added a few dlls to the GAC using gacutil and solved a few issues that way, however I'm seeing an error regarding a reference to System.Net.Http version 2.0.0.0.

I don't have a single reference to this DLL in my solution, I don't have this DLL anywhere on my machine in fact, only version 1.0.0.0 or 4.0.0.0.

I do have a binding redirect for this dll in my config file for the web site but obviously the code analysis process isn't using this.

I'm not sure how best to proceed with this. Can I configure code analysis to use the binding redirects? Or do I need to go hunting for DLLs online in order to GAC them?

Would appreciate any ideas, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to just GAC version 1.0.0.0 and code analysis is now working fine ...